# Why are my checkboxes unchecked when clicking on another? (Vue, CSS)

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm learning Vue and set myself the task to create a to do list. To make it prettier, I wanted to style my checkboxes and used [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) as a basis.

It works mostly fine: I can click on undone tasks to make them done and the other way round. However, if I click on a done task, the next done task (if there is any) gets the styling of an undone task (while correctly staying in the done department). It looks like this:

[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening. Can you? Thanks for any help!

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div style="margin: 10px">
    <input class="newTaskInput" type="text" v-model="newTask" placeholder="Neue Aufgabe">
    <button class="newTaskButton" v-on:click="addTask()">Hinzufügen</button>

    <h3>Offene Aufgaben</h3>
    <div class="taskBox">

      <label class="checkbox-container" v-for="t in unDoneTasks" :key="t.task">
        {{t.task}}
        <input type="checkbox" @click="change_task_state(t)">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

      <span v-if="unDoneTasks.length == 0">Alle Aufgaben erledigt!</span>
    </div>

    <h3>Abgeschlossene Aufgaben</h3>
    <div class="taskBox">

      <label class="checkbox-container" v-for="(t, index) in doneTasks" :key="index">
        <span class="done">{{t.task}}</span>
        <input type="checkbox" checked @click="change_task_state(t)">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

      <span v-if="doneTasks.length == 0">Noch nix erledigt!</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [
        { task: 'Milch kaufen', isDone: false },
        { task: 'Aufräumen', isDone: false },
        { task: 'Essen kochen', isDone: false },
        { task: 'Fahrrad reparieren', isDone: true },
      ],
      newTask: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    change_task_state(e) {
      e.isDone = !e.isDone;
    },
    addTask() {
      this.tasks.push({ task: this.newTask, isDone: false });
      this.newTask = '';
    },
  },
  computed: {
    unDoneTasks() {
      return this.tasks.filter((t) => !t.isDone);
    },
    doneTasks() {
      return this.tasks.filter((t) => t.isDone);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
/* CHECKBOX STYLING */
// Customize the label (the checkbox-container)
.checkbox-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

// Hide the browser's default checkbox
.checkbox-container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

// Create a custom checkbox
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 19px;
  width: 19px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

// On mouse-hover
.checkbox-container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: coral;
}
.checkbox-container:hover input ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

// When the checkbox is checked
.checkbox-container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.checkbox-container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

// Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked)
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

// Style the checkmark/indicator
.checkbox-container .checkmark:after {
  left: 6px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
/* Checkbox end */

.done {
  color: lightgrey;
}
.taskBox {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.newTaskInput {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
::placeholder {
  color: black;
}
.newTaskButton {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: coral 3px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting bitten by a combination of factors:

1. You aren't keying the items correctly. Keying by index in the list does not uniquely identify that item because the item indices will change when they get moved around.
2. The `checked` attribute only determines the *initial* checked state of the checkbox. Adding or removing this attribute has no effect on the checkbox after it is already created.

Vue's DOM patching algorithm tries to re-use existing DOM nodes whenever possible. When items get moved around, Vue will add or remove the `checked` attribute from the checkbox at the new index, which will not change the checked state of the checkbox.

There are 2 ways to fix it:

1. (Recommended) Use a key which always uniquely identifies the given item, even when it is moved around in the list. The `v-for` index won't work because the index will change. By doing this, Vue will preserve the `<input>` that corresponds to that item, thus preserving its checked state.

   For some deliberate reason, Vue does not allow using the object instance as the key, which would be perfect in this situation, so you have to maintain a key for each item manually; a `Symbol` will work.

   ```html
   <label class="checkbox-container" v-for="t in unDoneTasks" :key="t.key">
                                                                    ^^^^^
   ```

   ```js
   { key: Symbol(), task: 'Buy milk', isDone: false }
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. Force Vue to set the `checked` DOM property instead of the attribute.

   ```html
   <!-- Unchecked -->
   <input type="checkbox" :checked.prop="false" @click="change_task_state(t)">
   ```

   ```html
   <!-- Checked -->
   <input type="checkbox" :checked.prop="true" @click="change_task_state(t)">
   ```

   Observe the difference between the `checked` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#checked) and the `checked` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties_checkbox_radio):

   ```js
   const checkbox = document.querySelector('#my-checkbox')
   checkbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked')  // Attribute
   checkbox.checked = true;  // Property
   ```

Comment: Great, I used the first approach and it works perfectly! As I understand it, there can be no equal symbols so that the identifier is truely unique - correct?

Comment: Yes. `Symbol()` creates a new unique symbol. Refer to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). I recommended using a symbol because the alternative would be to use a number that you have to increment; a symbol is simpler and safer.